# Serve GeoServer Tiles in XYZ format

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, tiles

I am using GeoServer and seed tiles on my server. The tiles are created successfully but I don't know which pattern the directory structure is following... (i.e. .../EPSG_4326_05/0_0/00_06.png).

I want to use the tiles in a OpenLayers application and there I want to use a OSM source which is using the XYZ-pattern which is commonly used as URL pattern for tile-serving. Is there a way to tell the GeoServer it should create the tiles with the XYZ structure?

Comment: please don't duplicate questions across sites - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287161/serve-geoserver-tiles-in-xyz-format

Comment: i'm sorry... as i noticed, that the question would be better here, the post on stackoverflow was already made... 
i answered there with the link to this post

Comment: I just added an answer to it (the same/duplicate question) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55807135/687896

Answer (score 1):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) (actually [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/)) can provide a [number of end points](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/index.html) that can serve tiles.

None of these uses the so called XYZ system (because that isn't a standard) but [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) has a Tiled Layer that can handle TMS and WMTS servers using the [TileImage source](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.TileImage.html).

Comment: XYZ is not available because nobody contributed it :-p 
The Google maps endpoint is not a standard, but it's there anyways (wondering, is the Google one matching the XYZ one by any chance?)
Looking at this doc it seems like it might: http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/caching_data/using_gwc.html#geowebcache-with-google-maps

Comment: is there no possibility to transform the one pattern to the other?

i mean.. i get the url "EPSG_4326_05/0_0/00_06.png" and can recalculate it to the corresponding XYZ tile i.e.  "EPSG_4326_05/0/6.png"

Comment: and not only google maps is using this endpoint... the openstreetmap (source.OSM in openlayers) also have such a pattern